# How create loop in twig template?

Tags: laravel, twig

I want made loop like of this on twig template:

```
for($i=1;$i<100;$i++) {
 echo $i;
}
```

I solved this problem as:

```
{% if k > 0 %}
 {% for i in 0..k - 1 %}
      <div></div>
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

if k = 0 -> no loop
if k = 1 -> 1 loop
if k = 100 -> 100 lopp
```

May be is other solve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [range](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/range.html) to reproduce loop output similar to the first php example

```
{% for i in range(1, 100-1) %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `if` inside the `loop`

```
{% for i in 0..k if k > 0 %}
 {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/4scv20)

---

*edit: This doesn't work anymore in twig 3.X. You have to place the `if` inside the codeblock*